# Strange anomalies when converting an array of chars to a string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, type-conversion

I am attempting to build a program that utilizes a substitution table and a key to generate a cipher/encrypted text. So far, I have successfully stored the encrypted text in a char array. If I iterate through the text using a for loop, it works flawlessly every time. However, I need to return the encrypted text as a string. Here is the method I'm using...

```
string ciphertext = cipherArray; //cipherArray is of type char
```

When I attempt to cout the ciphertext, it will output normally sometimes, and other times it will display a few correct letters and then strange symbols. When I used a for loop to print the array, it worked fine, but converting it to a string is giving me issues. It seems like it is storing items that are out of range when it is converting from char to string.

Here is the full program: (Problem is under the encipher method definition)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//=============================================================================
//                          -Cipher Class-
//
class Cipher {
    public:
        Cipher();
        Cipher(string key);
        Cipher(string key, string message);

        void newKey();
        string inputMessage();
        string encipher(string message);
        string decipher(string message);
        string getPlainText() const;
        string getCipherText() const;

    private:
        void initAlphabet();
        void initTable();

        char alphabet[26];
        char table[26][26];
        string key;
        string plaintext;
        string ciphertext;
};

//=============================================================================
//                          -Main-
//
int main()  {
    Cipher myCipher;

    cout << "Key: ";
    myCipher.newKey();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Message: ";
    myCipher.encipher(myCipher.inputMessage());


    return 0;
}

//=============================================================================
//                          -Constructor-
//
Cipher::Cipher() {
    initAlphabet();
    initTable();
}

//=============================================================================
//                          -Initialize Alphabet-
//
void Cipher::initAlphabet() {

    char alphaStore[26] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
                         'n','o', 'p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        alphabet[i] = alphaStore[i];
}

//=============================================================================
//                          -Initialize Table-
//
void Cipher::initTable() {

    int alphaIndex = 0;

    for (int index1 = 0; index1 < 26; index1++) {
        for (int index2 = 0; index2 < 26; index2++) {   

            if ((index1 + index2) < 26) {
                alphaIndex = index1 + index2;
                table[index1][index2] = alphabet[alphaIndex];
            }
            else
                alphaIndex = 0;

            while (((index1 + index2) > 25) && index2 < 26) {
                table[index1][index2] = alphabet[alphaIndex];
                index2++;
                alphaIndex++;
            }           
        }               
    }
}


//=============================================================================
//                          -Input Message-
//
string Cipher::inputMessage() {
    cin >> plaintext;
    return plaintext;
}

//=============================================================================
//                          -New Key-
//
void Cipher::newKey() {
    cin >> key;
}

//=============================================================================
//                          -Encipher-
//
string Cipher::encipher(string message) {

    int iTableRow, iTableCol, i;
    unsigned int iKey, iMsg;
    int keyValStorage[key.length()];
    int msgValStorage[message.length()];
    char cipherArray[message.length()];    

    for (iKey = 0; iKey < key.length(); iKey++)
        for (iTableCol = 0; iTableCol < 26; iTableCol++)
            if (key[iKey] == table[0][iTableCol]) {
                keyValStorage[iKey] = iTableCol;
                iTableCol = 26;
            }

    for (iMsg = 0; iMsg < message.length(); iMsg++)
        for (iTableRow = 0; iTableRow < 26; iTableRow++)
            if (message[iMsg] == table [0][iTableRow]){
                msgValStorage[iMsg] = iTableRow;
                iTableRow = 26;
            }

    for (iKey = 0, iMsg = 0; iMsg < message.length(); iKey++, iMsg++) {
        if (iKey > (key.length() - 1))
            iKey = 0;
        cipherArray[iMsg] = table[keyValStorage[iKey]][msgValStorage[iMsg]];
    }         

    for (iKey = 0; iKey < message.length(); iKey++) 
        cout << cipherArray[iKey] << " ";   //This prints the encrypted text fine

    ciphertext = cipherArray; //This produces anomalies in the output.
    cout << ciphertext;

    return "placeholder";             

}
```

Comment: How are you expecting the constructor to know how many bytes to copy? (How did your `for` loop know? Post some code.)

Comment: Okay, when I printed the cipherArray using a for loop, I used the length of the original message(to be encrypted) as a limit.

How do I specify this when converting the char array to a string type?

The size of cipherArray is always the same as the length of the original message to be encrypted.

Comment: You have to be like Arnold and terminate the string....or provide a begin and end iterators. Just depends on how you construct the instance of `std::string`

Comment: @Victor Use a constructor that takes a range or sequence. It can't work by magic. (I could show you the actual code if you showed us some of your code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std:string` has a [constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) that takes a `char` buffer and a string length. Just use:

```
string ciphertext = string(cipherArray, /*length_of_cipherArray_here*/);
```

or even shorter:

```
string ciphertext(cipherArray, /*length_of_cipherArray_here*/);
```

Of course, this assumes that cipherArray is a `char[]` or `char*`.